# Set toolbar button width appropriately in Interface Builder

Tags: swift, macos, interface-builder, appkit, macos-big-sur

I've created a blank project, and added a toolbar to the main window. To it, I've added two "Textured Rounded Button[s]" from the object library. I've left one as-is, and the other I've customized by setting the image.

At runtime, they look correct, with the correct width automatically inferred:

[image]

However, this doesn't match the interface builder preview:

[image]

The button's width was set when it used to have the title "Textured Rounded", but it didn't readjust its width after removing the title and adding the icon.

It bugs me that my IB preview and runtime UI don't match. Of course, I can hand-tweak the button width, but that:

1. Suggests to me I'm doing it wrong
2. Is going to break in the future, similar to how my mis-configured toolbar buttons started looking wonky in Big Sur.

What's the correct way to add a button to a toolbar, in interface builder?

Comment: If you are laying an NSView guy under the text field, that's a Big Sur bug to my knowledge.  There is NOTHING you can do about it for now.

Comment: "f you are laying an NSView guy under the text field" What do you mean by this, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with macOS 11, toolbar items are automatically sized according the content, unless 'Explicit' sizing is selected for the selected `NSToolbarItem` in the Size inspector. Unfortunately this does not affect the sizes in the interface designer.

It's perhaps good to know that with macOS 11 and later, there is no need drag a `NSButton` to the interface designer, if you only want a button with an image. You can simply directly set the image in the `NSToolbarItem`, leave 'Title' empty, and when you check setting 'Bordered', the toolbar item will have the correct hovering effect.